# Connecting my NSManagedObject subclass with my ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

**OVERVIEW**

This is probably an extremely dumb/simple question, but it seems to be throwing me through a loop. I have created a NSManagedObject subclass for my entity "UsedInfo" per the advice of my fellows on StackOverflow. My ultimate goal is to use this subclass to send User information to CoreData, and later retrieve it.

**THE ISSUE**

The issue is that i cannot figure out how to use my new file, "UsedInfo+CoreDataProperties.swift", with my "ViewController.swift" file, which is where my TextFields are connected. Below you'll find the relevant code.

**Code for ViewController.swift (SaveButton)**

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("UsedInfo", inManagedObjectContext:context) as NSManagedObject

    let one = pickerTextField.text
    let two = modelName.text
    let three = serialNo.text
    let four = YOM.text
    let five = engineHours.text
    let six = locationOfMachine.text

    entity1.setValue(one, forKey: "product")
    entity1.setValue(two, forKey:"modelName")
    entity1.setValue(three, forKey:"serialNo")
    entity1.setValue(four, forKey:"yom")
    entity1.setValue(five, forKey:"engineHours")
    entity1.setValue(six, forKey:"location")
    print(entity1.valueForKey("product"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("modelName"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("serialNo"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("yom"))
    print(entity1.valueForKey("engineHours"))


    do {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }


}
```

**Code for "UsedInfo+CoreDataProperties.swift"**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension UsedInfo {

@NSManaged var engineHours: String?
@NSManaged var location: String?
@NSManaged var modelName: String?
@NSManaged var product: String?
@NSManaged var serialNo: String?
@NSManaged var yom: String?

}
```

**Code for "UsedInfo.swift"**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
class UsedInfo: NSManagedObject {

    //Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}
```

I thank you folks in advance. I'm sorry for my utter noob-ness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you created a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, you can use that subclass without any special steps to "connect" it. It's ready, and it can do anything defined by `NSManagedObject` as well as anything added in the new subclass.

With Core Data you'd start by changing the code that creates a new instance to be something like

```
let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("UsedInfo", inManagedObjectContext:context) as NSManagedObject as! UsedInfo
```

The call to `insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_:inManagedObjectContext:)` will create an instance of `UsedInfo`, but you need to add the `as! UsedInfo` to make it clear that's what you're getting. Using `as!` can be dangerous but it's not a bad idea here, because if this downcast fails, you want to know *immediately* so that you can fix your managed object model.

After that, `entity1` is an instance of your new `UsedInfo` class. You can use the properties declared on `UsedInfo` in the code below. For example,

```
entity1.product = one
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you, Tom. I know my questions seem dumb, i'm just not used to iOS development whatsoever.